# Hiding the article ID in a Joomla menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template, joomla-sef-urls

I have a series of sequentially-numbered items in several named categories, which appear as numbered lists on [this page](http://vision2020.org.uk/wishlist2.html). However, the added article ID in the URL is confusing the client.

I know that Joomla now [adds the article ID to URLs](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1248852), and that there is [no easy way](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1757771) of [removing it](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1685494). The last time I needed to alter something I hacked the relevant template, but writing URLs is more involved.

I need this:
    http://vision2020.org.uk/wishlist-for-retail/131-16-local-shops.html

to become:
    http://vision2020.org.uk/wishlist-for-retail/16-local-shops.html

Has anyone tackled this issue without resorting to a (possibly outdated or bloated) plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

Try use a SEF component like ACEsef or sh404sef which lets you customise each url. This will be far easier than you trying to change the com_content component in order to fix your urls.

Comment: Looks like that's the easiest route, although I don't like adding stuff that comes with a load of baggage I won't use (or paying extras for it if I do). I'd still like to know where the actual code is...

Comment: I forgot to add that we're using Joomla 1.6, so JoomSEF seems the only option. But - looking through that - I still think a manual mod_rewrite rule would be much simpler :-)

Comment: You can find the file you are looking for here components/com_content/router.php. Good luck changing it though.

Comment: took a look, but I think that may be too early in the process... components/com_weblinks/router.php seems to be where the components for the links are gathered - what I might need is where the URLs are actually constructed, but at the point after the database has been queried?